# How to plot interaction effects of pooled regression coefficents of multiple imputed data using mice in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, imputation, r-mice, emmeans

I've conducted a multilevel regression analysis using imputed data in R, utilizing the mice package. Here's my workflow:

I initially imputed my dataset using the mice package.
Next, I performed a multilevel regression analysis using the imp() function within the mice package.
Afterward, I pooled the regression coefficients.
Now, I'm facing a challenge when attempting to plot interaction effects. The issue arises because the model with the pooled results is represented as a 'mipo' object or a substantial 'mira' object.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to effectively create plots for interaction effects with this type of object.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Here is what I've done so far:

```
# Pool regression coeffcients from MI
pooled_model <- pool(mi_wellbeing)
summary_table <- summary(pooled_model, conf.int = TRUE)

# extracting interaction effects 
em_int.pooled <- emmeans(mi_wellbeing, ~gaming.cw*native.gmc, pbkrtest.limit = 3078)
tidy <- as_tibble(em_int.pooled)

#plotting
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)

ggplot(tidy, aes(y = gaming.cw, x = emmean, colour = factor(native.gmc))) +
  geom_linerangeh(aes(xmin = lower.CL, xmax = upper.CL), position = pd, size = 2) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 4) +
  ggtitle('Interactions') +
  labs(x = "Aggregated Interaction Effect") +
  scale_color_bright() +
  theme_nice()
```

Comment: Could you please make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?